# Nginx-fpm "No input file specified" (non-root directory)

Tags: php, nginx, vhosts, owncloud

i need help in nginx-fpm, i'm facing a problem about "no input file specified."

Here is my setting:

- /home/user/**website/public_html**  <== my web-development directory
- /home/user/**website/public_html** <==**symlink**==> to /usr/share/nginx/**html/**

**site-available/default** setup config:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    autoindex on;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;

    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
}
```

In this case, i was tried to install **ownCloud** and with that config i got an error like this:

```
    [error] 5541#0: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
            "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php (No such file or directory)" 
            while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, 
            request: "GET /public_html/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ HTTP/1.1", 
            upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost",     
            referrer: "http://localhost/public_html/owncloud/index.php"
```

Where is the problem? is it because the symlink or the config ?